# Don't get updates on realm models work with RecyclerView/DataBinding

Tags: java, android-recyclerview, realm, rx-binding

While implementing a solution based on Realm Mobile Database, RecyclerView and DataBinding I am stuck in receiving a change notification from an edittext view (within recyclerview) that is bound to a realm model. I tried it with RxBinding (my favourite) but without success - when it came to item.setName()... It crashed.

```
final int row = vh.getAdapterPosition();
    final android.widget.EditText editText = (EditText)vh.itemView.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
    Subscription editTextSub =
            RxTextView.textChanges(editText)
                    .subscribe(new Action1<CharSequence>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(CharSequence charSequence) {
                            if (row != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                                CrngyMaster item = (CrngyMaster) getItem(row);
                                item.setName(charSequence.toString());
                            }
                        }
                    });
    // Make sure to unsubscribe the subscription
```

I changed the code to:

```
Subscription editTextSub =
            RxTextView.textChanges(editText)
                    .subscribe(new Action1<CharSequence>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(CharSequence charSequence) {
                            int row = vh.getAdapterPosition();
                            if (row != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                                CrngyMaster item = (CrngyMaster) getItem(row);
                                String oldName = item.getName();
                                String modified = charSequence.toString();
                                if(Objects.equals(oldName, modified) == false) {
                                    CrngyMaster original = realm.where(CrngyMaster.class)
                                            .equalTo("mName", oldName)
                                            .findFirst();

                                    realm.beginTransaction();
                                    original.setName(modified);
                                    realm.commitTransaction();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
    // Make sure to unsubscribe the subscription
```

Now it's working, but:
- is this the way it should be implemented? I will add primary keys but I want to prevent the items from being queried when the recyclerview is loaded. Is that possible? And the most important question: how do I unsubscribe?

Comment: It depends on your usecase, because typically the editable copy is a detached object, and then you save it back to the Realm in a single transaction. Also, move the query inside the transaction.

Comment: Generally spoken, even if it's a detached object, I thought it's possible to modify that object. Is that true? I thought I collect the changes (in the detached object) and write that to db only once.